# Is there a publication database or search engine offering geneID or UniProtID correlation?

Tags: proteins, gene, database, phylogenetics, uniprot

Do we have a publication database or search engine that offers geneID or UniProtID correlation?

For example, I search "IPS cells" -> I want to know what genes or proteins are under active research in IPS cells.

Answer (score 4):

I think this could be close to what you're looking for: http://glad4u.zhang-lab.org/index.php

Paper: [GLAD4U: deriving and prioritizing gene lists from PubMed literature](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/23282288/)

It works with gene names though, so I am not sure it's a 100% fit.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at **GeneWalk**, https://churchman.med.harvard.edu/genewalk. It's a very interesting solution to this rather difficult problem. It is well documented and packaged. But It's open source software -- not a service. You'll have to run it on your own system.